# Nested web browser?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've got a listbox with some data (using ItemTemplate and StackPanel) in a Pivot. Currently, clicking on an item opens WEbBrowserTask going to certain url in item. Would it be possible to open the web page in the current Pivot page, and have it close and again show the listbox when back button is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431812%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) control (initially invisible) to display the web page pointed to by the URL. Also, hook into the [`BackKeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.backkeypress%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) event of the page.

When the user clicks an item show the `WebBrowser` and open the URL using it. Then, when they press the back key, cancel navigation within the `BackKeyPress` event handler, and make the `WebBrowser` invisible.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a lok how this is implemented in PhoneGap ChildBrowser plugin
 https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/WindowsPhone/ChildBrowser/ChildBrowserCommand.cs